# Nginx sometimes fails TLS passthrough to Java 17 application

Tags: java, nginx, ssl, google-cloud-platform, nginx-ingress

We have a spring-boot application that runs perfectly fine by itself on both Java 11 and Java 17.
The spring-boot application is packaged as a docker container and runs inside gcp/gke kubernetes.
We use the nginx ingress to forward the traffic with tls-passthrough.
We use a Let's Encrypt certificate for our application.
The nginx does not have access to it (AFAICT), but considers it valid.

When using Java 11 everything works fine.
However, when using Java 17 the first (few) requests pass fine, but then I get a certificate error. The nginx generates/has a default ingress certificate, that it uses for the later requests. But I don't understand why it does serve that (sometimes) in the first place.
The error is reproducible with browsers and Java applications.
I did not manage to preproduce it with curl/openssl though.
After a short time/few minutes the error vanishes for the next (few) requests before it emerges again.
When adding the ingress certificate to the trusted certs in browsers I can see that the ingress requests are upgraded to HTTP2, the first few HTTP1 requests all use the correct certificate.

We tried with different java 17 base images (openjdk/eclipse-temurin + alpine/ununtu).
We tried to explicitly disable http2 in Java and the browser.
Nothing seems to work except for adding the self-signed certificate to the trust-store (which is obviously a no go for production).
We weren't able to reproduce this locally, but might be due to our local dev setup being only a simplified version of the cloud environments.
If I use kubectl port-forward into the java app container, I cannot reproduce the issue.

We use the following versions:

- nginx-ingress-1.41.3
- gke v1.21.6-gke.1500
- eclipse-temurin 17
- spring-boot 2.6.3 with the default tomcat

TLDR: The nginx-ingress sometimes does not tls-passthrough to our Java 17 app correctly and thus serves an invalid certificate for those requests. (All responses contain the expected/same/valid content except for the certificate).
Has anyone an idea what is happening and how to fix/avoid that?

Comment: Did you give "latest" Oracle JDK 17 (or OpenJDK built by Oracle) a try? Seems to be a solution for this TLS/timeout-related issue here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2859

Comment: I had the same issues with OpenJDK.

Comment: @ST-DDT Did you find  a solution for this with java 17 or later version ?

Comment: @SanyamGoel Unfortunately not. I kind of feel alone and lost with this issue. I haven't tried again with the latest versions, though.

Comment: @ST-DDT I faced the same issue few days back and it took some time to understand this behavior and finally came across your post which is exactly what is happening in my case too.  Your suggestion to use Java 11 is what I am doing too at the moment.  When backend applications communicate directly without kubernetes (both client and Server on Java 17) there is no issue, but when the same communication happens via ingress, I see bad certificate error  in the ingress controller log which emerges and vanishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the exact same issue, and we believe the cause to be

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/9540

If you cannot upgrade, as stated in the issue

> In the meantime, it seems that setting the Java system property jdk.tls.server.enableSessionTicketExtension to false on the server side will disable the TLS feature which is causing this problem.

seemed to solve the problem in our case.

Comment: Thanks for linking that issue. Fixed in https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/commit/5628f765fe883dd8c13ccd3084e9003ffd3e28d5 and released in helm chart v4.4.3 and controller v1.6.1